# html element style overwrites css style

Tags: html, css

someone overwrites the style from the css file in html with the element style, although no style options are specified in the tag element in html. In my case here it is about the <label> tag and the style element color, which is always set to rgb(255, 255, 255) although it is not defined in the html.

source:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

I hope one of you knows a solution for this.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Please do not post PICTURES of code

Comment: Try opening your page in incognito mode. It could be a plugin

Comment: I know 'LastPass' password vault app auto-fill causes issues with `login`, `user`, `password` and `email` classes and or ids.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)